# Need help in increasing accuracy of a pattern recognition neural network

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, pattern-recognition

I am trying to develop a character recognition system for Hindi language using Matlab as my project.

My dataset consists of around 15000 samples of binary skletonized images of single characters. These images are 30*30 pixels each. Attaching a image for example. This image (900 pixel values) are stored in X (making it a numOfSamples*900 sized variable) and Y is a numOfSamples*numberOfClasses sized vector having 1 at its class and 0 at all the others.

**visit to see the image of skeletonized character**: postimg.org/image/lgxh2zq1f/

I am using the following network

```
net=patternnet([500,250,125,65]);
```

The above network looks like,

**visit to view the network**: postimg.org/image/666qear15/

After I train the network,

```
[net,tr]=train(net,X,Y);
```

My ROC plot and performance plot look like following,

visit to view ROC plot: https://postimg.org/image/etb5woper/

visit to view performance plot: https://postimg.org/image/aij4rmsfd/

Now, in the ROC plot, at around 0.7 the curve bends even in the training plot. I am not able to understand why!

I am not able to get the required accuracy. Current accuracy is around 70% and expected is around 90+%.

I also experimented with other models such as SVM's, KNN, Ensemble all giving me approximately the same 70% result.

I am fairly new to Machine Learning, any sugessions would be appreciated.

Thanks

PS: sorry for the bad links! i'm a new user so cant post more than 2 links

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your ROC curves, it seems your classifier doesn't perform well. An ideal situation would be for all classes to have curves that extend towards the top left corner.